# How to include reCAPTCHA(version 3) in Sitecore Form 9.3.0?

Tags: sitecore-forms, recaptcha

How to include reCAPTCHA(version 3) in Sitecore Form 9.3.0 ?

Comment: Welcome, Sophie. Please be as descriptive as possible. While your question is straightforward, are you able to explain why you are asking and any solutions you may have tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to this article to create a `reCAPTCHA 3` with your Sitecore form.

https://dev.to/chandra_kodi/sitecore-google-recaptcha-v3-5d18

Here are the steps you can use to create the reCAPTCHA 3.

- Create a new model class - `GoogleRecaptchaV3.cs`

  ```
  public class GoogleRecaptchaV3 : StringInputViewModel
   {
       public string ApiKey { get; set; }

       public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

       protected override void InitItemProperties(Item item)
       {
           base.InitItemProperties(item);

           ApiKey = Sitecore.StringUtil.GetString(item.Fields["Api Key"]);
           ErrorMessage = Sitecore.StringUtil.GetString(item.Fields["Error Message"]);
       }

       protected override void UpdateItemFields(Item item)
       {
           base.UpdateItemFields(item);

           item.Fields["Api Key"].SetValue(ApiKey, true);
           item.Fields["Error Message"].SetValue(ErrorMessage, true);
       }
   }
  ```
- Create custom validation class - CaptchaV3Validator.cs

  ```
  public class CaptchaV3Validator : ValidationElement<string>
   {
       public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> ClientValidationRules
       {
           get
           {
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ApiKey))
               {
                   yield break;
               }
           }
       }

       protected virtual string ApiKey { get; set; }
       protected virtual string Title { get; set; }
       protected virtual string FieldName { get; set; }

       public CaptchaV3Validator(ValidationDataModel validationItem) : base(validationItem)
       {

       }

       public override void Initialize(object validationModel)
       {
           base.Initialize(validationModel);
           StringInputViewModel stringInputViewModel = validationModel as StringInputViewModel;
           if (stringInputViewModel != null)
           {
               var fieldItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(ID.Parse(stringInputViewModel.ItemId));
               if (fieldItem != null)
               {
                   this.ApiKey = fieldItem["Api Key"];
               }
               this.Title = stringInputViewModel.Title;
               this.FieldName = stringInputViewModel.Name;
           }
       }

       public override ValidationResult Validate(object value)
       {
           if (value == null)
           {
               return new ValidationResult("Captcha is Inavlid.");// ValidationResult.Success;
           }
           var isCaptchaValid = ValidateCaptcha((string)value, this.ApiKey);
           if (!isCaptchaValid)
           {
               return new ValidationResult(this.FormatMessage(new object[] { this.Title }));
           }
           return ValidationResult.Success;
       }
       public static bool ValidateCaptcha(string response, string secret)
       {
           HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

           var res = httpClient.GetAsync($"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" + secret + "&response=" + response + "").Result;

           if (res.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
               return false;

           string JSONres = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
           dynamic JSONdata = JObject.Parse(JSONres);

           if (JSONdata.success != "true")
               return false;

           return true;
       }
   }
  ```
- Create a View at location Views/FormBuilder/FieldTemplates- GoogleRecaptchaV3.cshtml

  ```
  @using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html
  @model Glass.Mapper.Training.FormFields.GoogleRecaptchaV3


  <input id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" class="@Model.CssClass" type="hidden" value="" />

  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=grecaptcha_ready&render=@Model.ApiKey"></script>
  <script>
   function grecaptcha_ready() {
       grecaptcha.ready(function () {
           grecaptcha.execute('@Model.ApiKey', { action: 'form' }).then(function (token) {
               document.getElementById("@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)").value = token;
           });
       });
   }
   var hiddenField = document.getElementById(@Html.Raw("\"" + Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value) + "\""));
   var parent = hiddenField.parentNode;
   if (parent.classList.contains("sc-formdesign-fieldcontainer")) {
       var textDiv = document.createElement("div");
       textDiv.innerHTML = "(ReCaptcha V3 Hidden Field)";
       parent.appendChild(textDiv);
   }
  ```

**CORE db**

Create a form property by copying one of existing items ”SingleLineText” and rename the copied item as “GoogleReCaptchaV3”. `/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Settings/GoogleReCaptchaV3`

**MASTER db**

- In the Sitecore Content Editor, navigate to /sitecore/templates/System/Forms/Fields.
- Then add new template with name “CustomRecaptchaV3” and select Base template `/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Template`
- This template must inherit as below
  [image]
- Create new Validation item at `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Validations` as `CaptchaV3 Validation`.
- Create new Field type at `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types/Security` with name `Google Recaptcha V3`.

Now we are ready to use ReCaptcha V3 in Forms. Go to Sitecore Forms and simply drag and drop Google ReCaptcha V3 field under Security.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi @Sumit, add necessary steps anyway. That answer is useless now from SEO perspective. And if in the future the link is not working anymore, it will be useless completely.

Comment: @MarekMusielak I have updated my answer and mentioned all necessary steps. thanks

Comment: @SumitBhatia Will this solution work for Sitecore SXA?

Comment: @Sophie Yes it will work with SXA

Comment: @Sumit, I have implemented this but my recaptcha is not placed on the sitecore form (which is on the overlay of the page), instead its loading back on the bottom of the main page.

Comment: @Sophie Are you sure you have put it into the correct placeholder?

Comment: @Sophie I think the answer resolved your issue asked in the question. if you find it helpful kindly mark it as accepted for future reference. Also the issue of the captcha not being placed in the right location looks like a different issue that we can cover in another question. Thanks